# Is there a way to tie SharePoint list template to a workflow

Tags: windows, sharepoint, workflow-foundation

Is there any way to tie a workflow or a custom workflow develop in WWF to a list template. This workflow would be generic where I can deploy this list template to any site.

Answer (score 0):

workflows are associated with a specific list or a content type. If you are creating your own list template from markup, you could create your own content type for use in the list and associate your workflow to that content type.

Comment: How would I link the content type with the list template? Do I need to apply the content type to a list and do "Save list as template".

Comment: You'd need to create the list template declaratively, through caml and deploy it. It isn't something you can just do via the web browser.